# QGIS composer paper presets

Tags: qgis, print-composer

How can I add custom paper sizes to the presets under the Composition tab?

If I save and reuse a template, only the Item properties are saved, not the Composition items, so I have to change the width and height of the paper every time.

Comment: Could you be more specific with your steps? I just customized my paper size and saved the template and reused with all properties i changed preserved. I'm trying to pinpoint where the issue may be with what your doing. Also, which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: If you chose custom under the presets you can enter your own dimensions. As for the composition tab you cannot save these settings in a print template (qpt-file) but only in a QGIS project (qgs-file). This looks to me like a WAD (WorkAsDesigned). Not sure what whyzar is saving? I tested in a Fedora QGIS 2.10.1 environment.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done it in QGIS3 is via a simple python script that runs on QGIS startup.
In the QGIS APPDATA folder (on Windows, this is found via
Settings>User Profiles>Open Active Profile folder - then going back up to the QGIS/QGIS3 folder, or %appdata% -> QGIS/QGIS3)

Once you're there. Create a new file called startup.py (or edit the one there if there already is one), edit the file, and add in these lines:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsPageSize, QgsLayoutSize, QgsUnitTypes

pageSizeRegistry = QgsApplication.pageSizeRegistry()
```

and then add in the page sizes you want:

```
pageSizeRegistry.add(QgsPageSize('reportsmall', QgsLayoutSize( 146,245, units=QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters), 'Report - Small'))
```

Save it, open QGIS, and your new paper size should be there in the page size options.

You can add a bunch of other page sizes via this method.